# Let $N \lhd G$ with index p, p a prime, then each subgroup $H$ of $G$ is a subgroup of $N$ or we have that $G=HN$ with $[H:H\cap N]=p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $N \lhd G$ with index p, p a prime, then each subgroup $H$ of $G$ is a subgroup of $N$ or we have that $G=HN$ with $[H:H\cap N]=p$.

Approaching this, lots of results pop up in my mind but I'm having troubles to get a good path.

Answer (score 3):

Since $G/N$ has order $p$, there are NO subgroups of $G/N$ besides $G/N$ itself, and the trivial subgroup $\{N\}$.

This means (via the Correspondence Theorem) that there are NO subgroups of $G$ containing $N$ besides $G$ and $N$.

Now, $HN$ is a subgroup of $G$ (since $N$ is normal), and contains $N$, so we have just two possibilities:

1. $HN = N \implies H \cap N = H \implies H \subseteq N$
2. $HN= G$, in which case:

$\left|\dfrac{H}{H \cap N}\right| = \left|\dfrac{HN}{N}\right| = |G/N| = p$ (by the Second Isomorphism Theorem).